# Fetus hearing sound stories in Mahabharata and Ramayana

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, ramayana, manuscripts

Can you list all the stories in Mahabharata and Ramayana where Fetus hears the sound in mother's womb?

This includes Shiv Puran, Vishnu Puran & Bal Ganesh mythologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mahabharata:

Abhimanyu: When Subhadra, Arjuna's wife, was pregnant with Abhimanyu, she fell asleep while Arjuna was narrating the method to break into the Chakravyuha battle formation. Abhimanyu, still in the womb, heard the conversation and later demonstrated his knowledge during the Kurukshetra war.
Ramayana:

Luv and Kush: When Sita was pregnant with Luv and Kush, they heard the Ramayana being recited by sage Valmiki. Even before their birth, they imbibed the epic in its entirety.
Shiv Purana:

Kartikeya: The son of Lord Shiva and Goddess Parvati, Kartikeya, was born from Parvati's thoughts and placed in the Ganges River. As a fetus, he heard the Vedas and other divine sounds while being nurtured by the river.
Vishnu Purana:

Prahlada: Prahlada, the devotee of Lord Vishnu and son of Hiranyakashipu, heard spiritual teachings from sage Narada while still in the womb.
Bal Ganesh mythology:

Ganesha: In some stories of Bal Ganesh, it is mentioned that Ganesha, as the son of Lord Shiva and Goddess Parvati, heard the divine sounds and teachings of his parents while being nurtured in Parvati's womb.